# Automatic saving when making certain number of changes

Tags: save, vim

Is it possible to set in `.vimrc` that vim saves the file every time I will change (insert, delete, modify) certain number of characters (not after time interval).

I have a bad habit to press `:w` every time I make some small edit and I'd like to get rid of this bad habit.

thank you

Comment: Why is it bad? I do this automatically once I stopped for thinking (whether or not I actually modified something).

Comment: Because it's too [often](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't have to save with Vim until you're actually done editing or need some external program to be able to see the current state of the file.  Vim periodically (both based on time and how much has changed) saves a [swap file](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/recover.txt.html#swap-file) for the buffer you're editing.  So, if Vim or your computer crashes and you haven't saved, you'll still be able to [recover](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/recover.txt.html#recovery) a relatively recent version of your file by restoring from the swap file.

Comment: So it's sufficient to save the file at the moment I quit? What will I lose in this case in the worst case?

Comment: "The swap file is updated after typing 200 characters or when you have not typed anything for four seconds. … You can change the 200 character count with the `'updatecount'` option.  You can set the time with the `'updatetime'` option."

Comment: Is sufficient `set updatecount=20` in `.vimrc`? Why did they choose 200? Isn't it many? Or is it based on some statistics (lost versus performance)?

Comment: "The reason why it is not kept up to date all the time is that this would slow down normal work too much."